# 405 Request method 'GET' not supported before client request hits Interceptor in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, interceptor, http-status-code-405

I have setup a `Interceptor` in my web application. It works fine and I see it getting invoked for all the requests except for one method which accepts `POST` requests only. It seems that Spring has mapping for all the controller methods and what request method (like `GET` or `POST`) is mapped to each controller method. Before `Interceptor` is invoked, it sees which request method is mapped to which controller method, and if it doesn't find it, it throws '405 Request method 'GET' not supported` error. So I want to know, how do I tackle that?

To be clear, lets say I have two methods in my controller.

```
@Controller
public class myController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test1(){      
        return "abc";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String test1(){      
        return "xyz";
    }
```

and this is my `Interceptor`:

```
public class URLInterceptors extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter  {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("REQUESTED SERVLET PATH IS: " + request.getServletPath());   
        return true;    
    }   
}
```

And there is no problem in the configuration either:

```
public class RootContextConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{   
    @Bean
    public URLInterceptors urlInterceptors(){
        return new URLInterceptors();
    }   
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(this.urlInterceptors());       
    }
    ....
}
```

Then, whenever a request is made for `"/test"`, my `Interceptor` is invoked perfectly fine. But whenever a request is made to `"/login"`, my `Interceptor` is never invoked. Instead I see a `405 Request method 'GET' not supported` error.

Comment: Change the `RequestMethod.POST` to `GET` for `/login`?

Comment: @ArsenDavtyan lol no. There is a better way of handling this. What if my login page receives a form? Then surely I will need POST.

Comment: The question is if you're getting `405 Request method 'GET' not supported` for `/login`, that means you're using `GET` from client side, instead of `POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

`405 Request method 'GET' not supported`

Means whatever client side request you are making against the servlet is a GET request. The problem isn't with the servlet. I don't know if you are using a REST client or a browser etc, but you need to check and make sure the request that is being sent to your servlet is a `POST`